# Execute last command with !! (Instead of just showing the last command)

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, iterm2

I want the `!!` command to execute the last command I ran. Currently, when I hit enter, it just prints the last command  I ran on a new terminal line, and I have to hit enter again. It worked with a single 'enter' press on a previous work station of mine, so I know it's possible.

Comment: Why not just hit up+enter?

Comment: You can also use Ctrl+p then Enter, which I find easier to type anyway

Comment: @ceejayoz 'Cause the up key is inconvenient

Comment: @Ben Personally, I find ! to be easier to type than ctrl + p

Comment: @samlandfried you be you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `bash`, the option `histverify` is probably on. Try `shopt -u histverify`, and see if you can begin to enjoy the immediate execution of previous commands again.

Comment: And for `zsh` you can use `unsetopt histverify`. Thanks!